# Powershell array scope; why is my array empty?

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to have an array and add elements to it from different functions in my script. My example below illustrates where I might be misunderstanding something regarding scope. My understanding currently is that if an array is defined outside the function, and then elements are added inside the function, those elements should be available outside the function.

```
Function ListRunningServices
{
    $services+= Get-Service | ?{$_.Status -eq "Running"} | sort Name | select Name;
}

$services = @();
ListRunningServices;
$services;
```

What am I missing here? Perhaps my style is completely wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$services` within the function block is scoped to the function.  You can do something like the following instead:

```
Function ListRunningServices {
    Get-Service | ?{$_.Status -eq "Running"} | sort Name | select Name
}

$services = ListRunningServices
$services
```

Else, you may explicitly use `global:` to alter the scope:

```
Function ListRunningServices {
    $global:services = Get-Service | ?{$_.Status -eq "Running"} | sort Name | select Name
}

$services = @()
ListRunningServices
$services
```

Comment: I want to add to the services array from many different functions in my script. Which is the best practise way to do that? Use `$global`?

Comment: I would avoid using `$global:` if possible. Is there a reason you could not supply `$services` as a parameter to the other functions?  It may help to see how you intend to interact with `$services` using the other functions.

Comment: Just testing the $global solution you posted and it doesn't produce any output.

Comment: I've just copy/pasted the second example into a new PS session and it produces identical output to the first example.

Comment: Interesting, if I paste into a Powershell window it works, but if I save into a file and then call the file as a script with .\file.ps1 I get no output.

Comment: You would need to source the PS1 if you want the `$global:` to reference the console's active session, else you're inside the session created in the scope of the script.

Comment: I like your first suggestion. +1 @MooMinTroll: Use parameters as much as you can.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might post a follow-up question

Comment: Follow-up posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523398/best-way-to-add-results-to-an-array-across-multiple-functions-in-powershell

Answer (score 7):

You can solve this with global variables, but using globals is genereally considered bad practice.  If you use a generic collection type, like arraylist, instead of an array then you have an add() method that will update the collection in a parent scope without needing to explicitly scope it in the function:

```
Function ListRunningServices
{
    Get-Service | ?{$_.Status -eq "Running"} | sort Name | select Name |
     ForEach-Object {$services.add($_)}
}

$services = New-Object collections.arraylist
ListRunningServices
$services
```

Answer (score 4):

$service in the scope of the function has nothing to do with the one outside the function.

Try :

```
Function ListRunningServices
{
    $services = @()
    $services+= Get-Service | ?{$_.Status -eq "Running"} | sort Name | select Name;
    return $services
}


$services = ListRunningServices
$services
```

Keeping most of your code you can use :

```
Function ListRunningServices
{
    $global:services+= Get-Service | ?{$_.Status -eq "Running"} | sort Name | select Name;
}

$services = @();
ListRunningServices;
$services;
```

You can read the full explanation in [About_scope](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849%28v=wps.620%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Powershell requires specifying the `scope` with **prefixes** on `array` variables. Seems that "normal `String`" variables don't. Use them like this:

```
# Visible everywhere inside the script file (f.ex: myNameScript.ps1)
$script:names = @()

Function AddStringToArray ([string]$i_name) {
    $script:names += $i_name
}

AddStringToArray -i_name "Markie"
AddStringToArray -i_name "Harry"
```

I know this is late, but I hope this helps at least someone.