# Best way to add results to an array across multiple functions in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to perform a series of checks on some infrastructure, and if the check fails, add it to a list. At the end of the workflow, write the results list. Pseudo code:

```
Function CheckSomething
{
    # Perform a check here. If check failed, add to the results list.
}

Function CheckSomethingElse
{
    # Perform another check. If check failed, add to the results list.
}

Function ShowResults
{
    $results;
}

CheckSomething;
CheckSomethingElse;
ShowResults;
```

I would like to avoid using global variables. How would you solve it? Use a `collections.arraylist`?

**Update**

I tried the following suggestion from @mjolinor

```
Function CheckSomething
{
   # Perform a check here. If check failed, add to the results list
   $check = $true
   if ($check -eq $true) {$results[CheckSomething] = 'Pass'}
   else {$results[CheckSomething] = 'Fail}'
}

Function CheckSomethingElse
{
    # Perform another check. If check failed, add to the results list.
    $check = $false
    if ($check -eq $true) {$results[CheckSomethingElse] = 'Pass'}
    else {$results[CheckSomethingElse] = 'Fail}'

}

Function ShowResults
{
    $results;
}

$results = @{}
CheckSomething
CheckSomethingElse
ShowResults
```

And I get:

```
Missing or invalid array index expression.
At C:\Users\moomin\Documents\errorsTest.ps1:5 char:36
+    if ($check -eq $true) {$results[ <<<< CheckSomething] = 'Pass'}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: ([:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArrayIndexExpression
```

This is a follow-on question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520980/powershell-array-scope-why-is-my-array-empty).

Comment: What type of variable you use has no bearing on the use of a global/non-global variable. Some people would say that there is nothing wrong with a global variable or singleton object. A lot of times they would be right. Personally I tend to avoid them because I feel it makes my code more portable. The way to avoid one in your case is to return the failed list as an array and add it to an array that is technically in the global scope but not being directly accessed in the individual functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use a hash table:

```
Function CheckSomething
{
   # Perform a check here. If check failed, add to the results list.
   if ($check -eq $true) {$results['CheckSomething'] = 'Pass'}
   else {$results['CheckSomething'] = 'Fail}'
}

Function CheckSomethingElse
{
    # Perform another check. If check failed, add to the results list.
    if ($check -eq $true) {$results['CheckSomethingElse'] = 'Pass'}
    else {$results['CheckSomethingElse'] = 'Fail}'
}

Function ShowResults
{
    $results;
}

$Results = @{}
CheckSomething
CheckSomethingElse
ShowResults
```

Comment: This is still using a global variable which the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: It is using a variable in a parent scope, but that is not the same thing as using an explicitly global variable.

Comment: That's my fault. The name of the hash table key needs to be quoted. I've updated the posted script.

Comment: @mjolinor you are correct that it is not declared as a global. It still couples the functions just as much as a global though.

Comment: In this application, where there is a separate function to display the results some kind of coupling seems unavoidable.

Comment: Well since the only thing that the ShowResults function does is $results, I would say that there isn't much need for that function. Regardless it would be simple enough to pass in the object to display to remove the coupling.

Comment: As I said in my comment above it really is a matter of taste though.

Comment: I kind of assume examples may be over-simplified, and the actual application could be much more complicated.  I just attempted to show a way to accomplish this without involving global variables. Soembody apparently care for the taste of it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing your initial post, I believe the simplest way would be to take your original approach and use the `$Script:` scope:

```
Function CheckSomething
{
    # perform a check here, if check failed add to the results list
    $Script:results += 'Added Content'
}

Function CheckSomethingElse
{
    # perform another check,  if check failed add to the results list
    $Script:results += 'Added Content'
}

Function ShowResults
{
    $results;
}

$results = @();
CheckSomething;
CheckSomethingElse;
ShowResults;
```

Since you are defining `$results` at the script level already, you just need to make sure that inside your functions you are referencing that variable at the appropriate scope by append `$Script:`.